# iOS PushNotification iPhone and iPad

Tags: php, ios, ipad, push-notification

I have made one universal app having push notification feature. I am sure you will also get surprised by reading this.

In Production version (App store build) I am receiving Push message on my iPad while i haven't receive such Notification on my iPhone.

App is build for universal so of course code is same more over Appdelegate is same for both iPad and iPhone.

I have been making iOS since last 4 year never faced such issue.

One thing is for sure that my push notification implementation is correct otherwise i will never get push message on my iPad.

Any help ????

Thanks,
Parth

Amendment:

Please check below PHP code, Same code (copy/Past) working for my another app and for this it wont.
Again If i send push on single device i am receiving on all, but if i try to send to all device by using loop i have just receive on one device. (probably first row of table )

```
$payload = json_encode($body);
for($i = 0; $i<count($deviceTokens); $i++) {
$msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '',$deviceTokens[$i])) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($fp, $msg);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Here i place echo in for loop and i got all register devices.

Comment: Are you sure you are sending to both separately right?

Comment: Are you sending the message to each device token?

Comment: Yes, sending to all device, even received on my other iPads

Comment: I think this is not Apple side issue this mush be PHP server side coding issue. From MySql I have replace my DeviceToken(iPad) with my iPhone Token and now i received on my phone not on my iPad. What i am thinking is it's take only first record. So i have debug it and got one more surprise that it's not take just one, it's working/behaving as expected.

Comment: Got it, it might get DeviceToken issue, any how if you get another app device token (which general happen if you copy past code) then this kindda issue will be there. I fix it by simply remove all device tokens from db.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($deviceTokens); $i++) {

pushnotification_ios($deviceTokens, "Your Message");
}
```

**Call this function in loop..**

```
function pushnotification_ios($device_token, $message){

        $passphrase = "Your_PEM_File_Password_Here";

        $ctx = stream_context_create();
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', YOUR_PEM_FILE_PATH_HERE);
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
    // use this when you in sandbox mode..
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    // use this when you in development mode..
    //  $fp = stream_socket_client(
    //  'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    //$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

        $body['aps'] = array(
            'badge' => $badge,
            'alert' => $message,
            'sound' => 'default',
            'content-available' => '1'
        );
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($body);
        $payload = json_encode($body);

        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $device_token) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));  //echo "<pre>"; print_R($result);
        /*
        if (!$result){
            $data = array(
                'Message' => 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL
                );
            }  else {
        $data = array(
                'Message' => 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL
                );
        } //echo "<pre>"; print_R($result); */

        fclose($fp);
    return $result;
    }
```